# UISelector Using descriptionContains

Tags: android, selenium, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm working on the automation script, where I'm trying to click on the element based on content-desc, The code I tried is

```
app_element = driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().descriptionContains("Subway Surfers")')
app_element.click()
```

This works for me

But I want to know is it possible to store the 'Subway Surfers' in a string variable and assign it inside the descriptionContains("Subway Surfers")') like

```
 content_description = 'Subway Surfers'
 app_element = driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().descriptionContains(content_description)')
```

Like this is it possible can any one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
content_description = 'Subway Surfers'
app_element = driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().descriptionContains('+content_description+')')
```